# What does this eclipse error mean: "path for project must have only one segment"?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

There are a couple very similar questions here, except they are related to Android run/debug configurations. I'm trying to configure a GWT app. I get this error when I try to save a change in the properties. Specifically, in the project properties UI, I'm in Google->Web Application, and I'm trying to uncheck 'Launch and deploy from this directory'. I have 'This project has a WAR directory' property checked, and a valid folder in the "WAR directory" box.

The error says to check the eclipse error log for more details, so I did, but not much helpful there. Here's the top few lines from the stack trace there :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path for project must have only one segment.
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceRoot.getProject(WorkspaceRoot.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModel.getJavaProject(JavaModel.java:189)
at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.getJavaProject(JavaRuntime.java:1229)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.launch.LaunchConfigurationUtilities.getJavaProject(LaunchConfigurationUtilities.java:83)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.launch.LaunchConfigurationUtilities.getLaunchConfigurations(LaunchConfigurationUtilities.java:102)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.launch.processors.LaunchConfigAffectingChangesListener.updateLaunchConfigs(LaunchConfigAffectingChangesListener.java:248)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.launch.processors.LaunchConfigAffectingChangesListener.updateLaunchConfigurations(LaunchConfigAffectingChangesListener.java:238)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.launch.processors.LaunchConfigAffectingChangesListener.warOutLocationChanged(LaunchConfigAffectingChangesListener.java:243)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.properties.WebAppProjectProperties.notifyWarOutLocationChangedListeners(WebAppProjectProperties.java:236)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.properties.WebAppProjectProperties.setWarSrcDir(WebAppProjectProperties.java:208)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.properties.ui.WebappProjectPropertyPage.saveProjectProperties(WebappProjectPropertyPage.java:216)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.ui.AbstractProjectPropertyPage.performOk(AbstractProjectPropertyPage.java:77)
```

My workspace path has no spaces; it is C:\projects\eclipse\workspaces\MyProjectHasNoSpaces

I'm running eclipse Helios; GWT 2.5, java 1.6.0_45, Windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: Hopefully this will help: http://androblip.huiges.nl/2011/02/20/eclipseavd-path-for-project-must-have-only-one-segment/

Comment: thanks, but I already had a debug configuration, with this project referenced and the name of the debug config set; I don't think that's it

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse project importer sometimes gives useless generic error message.  The predictable way to get what the real error is to just open a terminal window and do "mvn clean compile" or something like that.  Then you may see more specific message like this:

```
Users/amrinder/xyz> mvn clean compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project xyzabc:[unknown-artifact-id]:1.0 (/Users/amrinder/xyzabc/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'artifactId' is missing. @ line 5, column 15
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```